# Web2Py IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed error for sending email

Tags: python, email, gmail, web2py, getaddrinfo

I've been getting the following error:

**WARNING:web2py:Mail.send failure:[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed**

for the following code:

```
mail = Mail()
mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
mail.settings.sender = 'email@gmail.com'
mail.settings.login = 'email@gmail.com:password'

mail.send(to=[email],subject= 'TEST',message='helloWorld')
```

Can someone please assist me? I can't seem to find any documentation on what getaddrinfo is and where in the code the error is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use smtplib to do it.

```
# here i check if i send succesfully.
server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
# server.login(username, password)  # optional
try:
    toaddr = TO
    cc = [CC]
    bcc = ['']
    toaddrs = [toaddr] + cc + bcc
    failed = server.sendmail(FROM, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.close()
    statusemail= "Email enviado com sucesso para %s" % TO
    print statusemail
    return statusemail
except Exception, e:
    errorMsg = "Unable to send email. Error: %s" % str(e)
    return errorMsg
##############################################################
#example code to test smtplib
import smtplib
# Specifying the from and to addresses
fromaddr = 'fromuser@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'touser@gmail.com'
# Writing the message (this message will appear in the email)
msg = 'Enter you message here'
# Gmail Login
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
# Sending the mail  
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

[image]

source: [link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/google/sending-emails-using-google)

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with your computer's network settings.
It is not a problem with your code.

Information about `getaddrinfo` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo)

If you are on a linux/unix-like system - you can try `nslookup smtp.gmail.com`